# Combine autocomplete with getopts

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I made a script called "gc" to autocomplete git branch names, when using the `git checkout` functionality, e.g. typing `gc mob-102` then pressing tab twice would display matching branch names such as mob-1025-a, mob-1025-b, mob-1021-end, etc.

```
function gc() {
  git checkout "$1"
}

_gc() {
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    local branch_names=$(git branch|xargs basename|grep -v '*')
    local tag_names=$(git tag)
    local remote_branch_names=$(git branch -r|xargs basename|grep -Ev "HEAD|->")
    local all_branch_and_tag_names=${branch_names}${remote_branch_names}${tag_names}
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${all_branch_and_tag_names}" $cur))
}
complete -F _gc gc
```

I put this into my .bash_profile, and that was fine. However, now I'm trying to add an optional "-b" option, so that you can also have the `git checkout -b <new branch name>` functionality, i.e. create a new branch from the current branch, e.g. 
`gc -b my_new_branch`.  If you don't pass the "-b" option, I'd want the autocomplete to work as before.

I've used `getopts` before in other scripts, but I can't seem to get this to work.  One approach I tried was:

```
    function gc() {
        if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
        then
          echo "There is more than one argument on the command line"
          while getopts ":b:" opt; do
            echo "Got an option: $OPTARG"
            case $opt in
              b)
                echo "Got the -b option with $OPTARG"
                git checkout -b "$OPTARG"
                ;;
             \?)
               echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
               exit 1
               ;;
            esac
          done
       else
          gc_branch_complete "$1"
       fi
    }

function gc_branch_complete() {
    git checkout "$1"
}

_gc() {
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    local branch_names=$(git branch|xargs basename|grep -v '*')
    local tag_names=$(git tag)
    local remote_branch_names=$(git branch -r|xargs basename|grep -Ev "HEAD|->")
    local all_branch_and_tag_names=${branch_names}${remote_branch_names}${tag_names}
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${all_branch_and_tag_names}" $cur))
}
complete -F _gc gc_branch_complete
```

Oddly, this seemed to work when run the first time, but not on subsequent invocations.

Are there any better approaches than this?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using the official git bash completion script?

Comment: Aha!  Good idea, I didn't know that existed (makes mental note to check before reinventing wheel next time).  Thanks @EtanReisner!

Comment: @EtanReisner After some experimentation, I've decided to combine my script above with the official git bash completion script. As typing "git chec" then tab, then the start of the branch name, then tab, is more typing than just "gc" and the start of the branch name, and tab.  At any rate, I'd be happy to accept your answer, if you wanted to add your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: My comment isn't an answer to the question though. A git alias of `co = checkout` solves most of that extra typing problem `git co bra<tab>` is longer than `gc bra<tab>` (but not hugely so). Also the official completion likely has functions that you can use directly as your shell function completion.

Comment: True.  Yes, I've been looking at the git aliases too, like the one you suggested.  OK, thanks again for your comments, I'll leave this open, just out of academic curiosity :)